# mongoose problm uri parameter

Tags: node.js, typescript2.0

```
at C:\Users\ELCOT\Desktop\chats app backend\chatsappbackend\chat-backend\node_modules\mongoose\lib\index.js:351:10
at C:\Users\ELCOT\Desktop\chats app backend\chatsappbackend\chat-backend\node_modules\mongoose\lib\helpers\promiseOrCallback.js:32:5
at new Promise (<anonymous>)
at promiseOrCallback (C:\Users\ELCOT\Desktop\chats app backend\chatsappbackend\chat-backend\node_modules\mongoose\lib\helpers\promiseOrCallback.js:31:10)
at Mongoose._promiseOrCallback (C:\Users\ELCOT\Desktop\chats app backend\chatsappbackend\chat-backend\node_modules\mongoose\lib\index.js:1149:10)
at Mongoose.connect (C:\Users\ELCOT\Desktop\chats app backend\chatsappbackend\chat-backend\node_modules\mongoose\lib\index.js:350:20)
at Object.connectDb (C:\Users\ELCOT\Desktop\chats app backend\chatsappbackend\chat-backend\src\config\index.ts:22:18)
at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\ELCOT\Desktop\chats app backend\chatsappbackend\chat-backend\src\server.ts:34:1)
at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1254:14)
at Module._compile (C:\Users\ELCOT\Desktop\chats app backend\chatsappbackend\chat-backend\node_modules\source-map-support\source-map-support.js:547:25)
at Module.m._compile (C:\Users\ELCOT\AppData\Local\Temp\ts-node-dev-hook-5569744297105346.js:69:33)
at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1308:10)
at require.extensions.<computed> (C:\Users\ELCOT\AppData\Local\Temp\ts-node-dev-hook-5569744297105346.js:71:20)
at Object.nodeDevHook [as .ts] (C:\Users\ELCOT\Desktop\chats app backend\chatsappbackend\chat-backend\node_modules\ts-node-dev\lib\hook.js:63:13)
at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1117:32)
[ERROR] 17:22:02 MongooseError: The `uri` parameter to `openUri()` must be a string, got "undefined". Make sure the first parameter to `mongoose.connect()` or `mongoose.createConnection()` is a string.
```

Please fix this error my chat application is not working. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please format your question properly. Besides which, try to do as it says, check the uri you are giving it to connect to mongodb. Somehow whatever you are giving is undefined. See this for more details: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/connections.html

Comment: If you could provide snippets of your code that where the Mongoose connection is being made. That would help

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.